# Transferring messages from a pst file to a webmail

Tags: email-client

I have a very old Pst file.
In that file I have a lot of folders and subfolders.
I am now wanting to transfer to a web-based email account
such as gmail, yahoo and so on...
I have not seen any way of importing messages from a pst file
to the web mail.
Does anyone know a webmail that supports this?

Answer (score 3):

If this is a one-time thing, open the .pst in Outlook, connect to the webmail service by IMAP and drag the mails over.